# How to pass through the soap memory stream?

Tags: c#, soap, blob, memorystream

I create memory stream.

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, list.ToArray());
```

And I need to pass through the soap to java server and insert to database.

And how create webService method ?

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "CreateObject")
    public String CreateTopology(
            @WebParam(name = "session")int id_session, 
            @WebParam(name = "title") String title, 
            @WebParam(name = "content") Object content,
            @WebParam(name = "access") Integer access) {
```

**EDIT:**
Problem. I have serialized object in C #. I need to pass it on to the server via SOAP Java, after that save it in MySQL database in field of type Blob (may not be the blob)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Forget about _how_ you think you should accomplish it, but _what_ are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @John Saunders, I edit my post

Comment: I have no idea what you're getting at. You don't have to do anything like this to create a web service. See the resources at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base64String - to pass as string

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, m_workspace.ListPlatforms.ToArray());

String base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

```
//build a Call object
   Call call = new Call();
   call.setTargetObjectURI("urn:greetingService");
   call.setMethodName("sayGreeting");
   call.setEncodingStyleURI(Constants.NS_URI_SOAP_ENC);

   //creating a parameter list
   Vector params = new Vector();
   params.addElement(new Parameter("name", String.class, name,null));

//adding the parameter(s) to the Call object
   call.setParams(params);
```

You are setting the method-name "sayGreeting" and in a vector params you specify the parameters which the method will be called with. This parameter-vector is what you need!

The code-sample is taken from page 2 of this tutorial which i very much recommend: http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/SOAP/

Comment: I do not understand what this class Call? We would simply request itself

Comment: one one computer you are creating this Call-object, then that call-object gets transmitted to another computer; That computer executes the Call-object. The Call-object contains the information 1) which method to call on the other computer and 2) with which parameters. `http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/SOAP/`